# My code is generating a message it is not supposed to generate even when all the criteria is filled. What is wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
def check_Driver(FName_Entry, LName_Entry, day_combobox, month_combobox, year_combobox,
                 myvar1, Email_Entry, Phone_Entry, event=None):
    FName = FName_Entry.get()
    LName = LName_Entry.get()
    Email = Email_Entry.get()
    Number = Phone_Entry.get()
    day = day_combobox.get()
    month = month_combobox.get()
    year = year_combobox.get()
    length = len(Number)

    if not FName.isalpha() and len(FName) != 0:
        errormsg = Message(root, text='Enter a valid first name', anchor=CENTER,
                           bg="red", width=1000)
        canvas.create_window(1020, 134, anchor=NW, window=errormsg)
        # messagebox.showerror('Only letters', 'Only letters are allowed!')

    if not LName.isalpha() and len(LName) != 0:
        errormsg2 = Message(root, text='Enter a valid last name', anchor=CENTER,
                            bg="red", width=1000)
        canvas.create_window(1020, 174, anchor=NW, window=errormsg2)

    if not Number.isdigit() or length != 11 and length != 0:
        errormsg5 = Message(root, text='Enter a valid phone number', anchor=CENTER,
                            bg="red", width=1000)
        canvas.create_window(1020, 334, anchor=NW, window=errormsg5)

    if not FName or LName or Email or Number or day or month or year:
        error_blank = Message(root, text="Please don't leave any field/s blank",
                              anchor=CENTER, bg="red", width=1000)
        canvas.create_window(600, 450, anchor=NW, window=error_blank)

    if int(myvar1.get()) not in (1, 2, 3):
       error_blank2 = Message(root, text="Please don't leave any field/s blank",
                              anchor=CENTER, bg="red", width=1000)
        canvas.create_window(600, 450, anchor=NW, window=error_blank2)

    if (FName.isalpha() and LName.isalpha() and Number.isdigit() and length == 11
        and myvar1.get() in [1,2,3] and len(Email) != 0 and len(day) != 0
        and len(month) != 0 and len(year) != 0):
```

According to this code, a "please dont leave any fields blank " is supposed to be generated if `FName` or `LName` or `Email` or `Number` or `day` or `month` or `year` is empty, but when I fill the form completely - it still generates this message and I can't move forward.

What is causing this?

Comment: Please follow the [PEP8 naming conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) and be consistent with your variable names. Write functions and variables with `lower_snake_case`, classes with `PascalCase` and constants with `SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE`. Following these conventions makes the code much easier to read and understand.

Answer (score 2):

```
if not FName or LName or Email or Number or day or month or year:
```

This needs a `not` before every variable individually. Right now, it's being interpreted as

```
if (not FName) or (LName) or (Email) . . .
```

So if `LName`, `Email`, or any of the rest are true, the entire condition will be, and the error will be shown.

Instead of negating each individually, you could also negate an [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) condition instead, which may be slightly cleaner:

```
if not all([FName, LName, Email, Number, day, month, year]):
```

That reads nicer as well.

Comment: Hi, I tried this but it is still giving me that message

Comment: I just removed that argument and it worked fine, so I see that myvar1.get() is the issue. I tried using int(myvar1.get()) but it gives me the error int object with invalid literal with base 10

Comment: I had tested it and it seemed to work then but it must have been  another factor that made it look like it was working - myvar is a Radiobutton which I am new to so I am a bit confused as well, but thank you for the advice!

Comment: I don't use tkinter, but if one element type returns `int`s, you may have switched from it to a different type that returns strings.